# Find size of file in MB

Tags: unix

How to find the size of file in MB in UNIX command line?

Comment: This question _does not_ belong on serverfault. Shell scripting is not necessarily 'server stuff'. Or shall we say that those who code in scripting languages are not programmers? Hm...

Comment: @Robert, very wrong.  Shell scripting is a vital part of any sysadmin's job.

Comment: Churnd is right. Command line is not necessarily shell scripting, ascertaining the status of a file system IS part of a SysAdmin's job, and shell scripting (JCL, Batch, whatever) IS part of a SysAdmin's job. This question DOES belong on ServerFault.

Answer (score 10):

If your `ls` supports `--block-size` such as GNU coreutils `ls` does:

```
ls -s --block-size=1048576 filename | cut -d' ' -f1
```

Answer (score 8):

`du -h file`

#### OR

`ls -lh file`

**EDIT**

this answer is wrong since it can report size also in Gb/Kb, depending on the file's size. **Please remove upvotes**.

Comment: Interestingly, I havw a `120672256` byte file that shows `116M` with `du` and, `115M` with the `ls` command...

Comment: Note: I am not at all suggesting these answers are incorrect. I would have done `du -sh` myself (which is what i did to check the difference with `ls`).

Comment: Ok, I think i have an answer for my question. The `du` counts disk space utilization for the file and the `ls` just counts the size of the file.

Comment: du -h should report the real size (allocated as multiple of your block  size)

Comment: There's also du --si for those who prefer 1000 over 1024

Comment: Close enough! Upvoted.

Answer (score 6):

I tend to use 'du -k myfile' to get kbytes and visually drop the last three digits,
but I'm just looking for approximate size.

Turns out that du often (always?) has -m option for MB.

Keep in mind that how large the file likely differs slightly from the amount of diskspace used, as the disk allocation occurs in blocks, not bytes.

If you are looking for 'fat' files because of low diskspace, that would be a more enlightening question, as the solutions would be more varied.

Answer (score 3):

using -lh option will give you sizes in human readable form, e.g if your file is of size 1025 M it will output 1G,
otherwise you can use ls --block-size=1024K -s it will give size in nearest integer in MBs.

If you need precise values (not rounded ones) you can go for awk:

```
ls -l | awk '/d|-/{printf("%.3f %s\n",$5/(1024*1024),$9)}'
```

Comment: you are right, my answer is wrong since it will report size in Gb/Mb/Kb

Comment: Nitpick: 1024*1024 uses MiB (=2^20) instead of the requested MB (10^6).
See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte

Answer (score 2):

`stat` can do this.

```
$ ls -l | grep myfile
-rw-------  1 rory rory      3120 2009-07-02 16:58 myfile
$ stat -c '%s' myfile
3120
```

that give it to you in bytes.

You can use bash's arithmetic to calculate the megabytes:

```
$ echo $(( $( stat -c '%s' myfile ) / 1024 / 1024 ))
0
```

(but it rounds it down in this case)

Comment: Useless use of grep. Just do ls -l myfile.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: Habit :P

Comment: stat is not on every flavor of *nix (or at least not installed by default).  When it's there, it's nice however.

Answer (score 2):

I found an AWK 1 liner, and it had a bug but I fixed it. I also added in PetaBytes after TeraBytes.

```
FILE_SIZE=234234 # FILESIZE IN BYTES
FILE_SIZE=$(echo "${FILE_SIZE}" | awk '{ split( "B KB MB GB TB PB" , v ); s=1; while( $1>1024 ){ $1/=1024; s++ } printf "%.2f %s", $1, v[s] }')
```

Considering **stat** is not on every single system, you can almost always use the AWK solution. Example; the Raspberry Pi does not have **stat** but it does have **awk**.

Comment: Remove the space after the equals symbol. Then it works well :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tiny Python script:

```
$ cat ./size_in_mb.py
#!/usr/local/bin/python
import os
import sys
print os.path.getsize(sys.argv[1])/1048576

$ ls -l test.tgz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 258330336 Jul  7 00:04 test.tgz

$ ./size_in_mb.py test.tgz
246
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw this on another thread and liked the results.  Under AIX, I used

```
ls -l [filename] | awk '{$5=sprintf("%.3f GB", $5/1024^3)} 1'
```

Produces the GB count with 3 decimal places

Example output of

```
ls -l /tmp/myfile:

-rw-rw-rw- 1 owner group 0.530 GB Jul 8 10:33 /tmp/myfile
```

You may opt to increase the decimal count if the file is smaller than 1 MB.  The example above, using %.9f instead would give:

```
0.530388314  GB
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this example:

```sh
size=$(du file |  awk '{print $1/1000}')

echo "the size is ${size} MB"
```